# Can't access key in json file

Tags: python, json

I try to work with this JSON file with python:
[JSON file](https://data.angers.fr/explore/dataset/arrets-reseau-irigo/download/?format=json&timezone=Europe/Berlin)

I want to access at `'lignes'` key with this code :

```
import json

with open('arrets-reseau-irigo.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

    for i in data:
        print("datasetid is {0}".format(i['datasetid']))
        print("nom arret is {0}".format(i['fields']['nom_arret']))
        print("coordonnées is {0}".format(i['fields']['geo_point_2d']))
        try :
            if format(i['fields']['lignes']) in data :
                print("Fields : is {0}".format(i['fields']['lignes']))
            else :
                print('nothing')
        except:
            print("EXCEPTION")
```

Result is:

```
datasetid is arrets-reseau-irigo
nom arret is GIRARD
coordonnées is [47.4909169756, -0.581150255698]
nothing
datasetid is arrets-reseau-irigo
nom arret is HOTEL DE VILLE TRAM B/C
coordonnées is [47.4716862858, -0.546754596835]
EXCEPTION
```

Do you have an example code to resolve my problem and show the value only if `'ligne'` key exists?

Comment: Can you show us how your json file looks like?

Comment: I don't see any "lignes" in that JSON file

Comment: I modify the link, was wrong sorry ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an example of file provided by you.

```
[
  {
    "datasetid": "arrets-reseau-irigo",
    "fields": {
      "accessib": "O",
      "date_maj": "Décembre 2016",
      "geo_point_2d": [
        47.4682358304,
        -0.550894481011
      ],
      "lignes": "L_1,L_1D,L_1S,L_2,L_2D,L_2S,L_3,L_3D,L_3S,L_4,L_6,L_10",
      "nom_arret": "FOCH - SAINT AUBIN",
      "source": "KEOLIS Réseau IRIGO"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        -0.550894481011,
        47.4682358304
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "record_timestamp": "2017-01-12T17:05:52+01:00",
    "recordid": "65e54c3d5e87a803c3a2199fbde5596e5833be8f"
  },
 ]
```

**Updated:**

```
import json

with open('file.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for i in data:
    print("datasetid is {0}".format(i['datasetid']))
    print("nom arret is {0}".format(i['fields']['nom_arret']))
    print("coordonnées is {0}".format(i['fields']['geo_point_2d']))
    description = i['fields'].get('lignes', 'nothing')
    print(description)
```

Comment: Hi @Taras, my file was wrong ^^ I modify the link. You can check it :)

Comment: *I want to access at 'lignes' key with this code*

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: That work ^^ but why it doesn't work with my code ? what the rules of 'get' ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this rightly, rather than the try/except you want to do

```
if 'lignes' in i['fields']:
    print("Fields : is {0}".format(i['fields']['lignes']))
else :
    print('nothing')
```

Comment: I try your code but it always show me 'nothing' :/

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the additional check `if format(i['fields']['lignes']) in data :` .

Answer (score 0):

The lingnes key does not exist in the example JSON file you posted, however it's at the same level as say 'format'. something like this

```
for count in data:
    if 'fields' in data[count]:
        print(data[count]['fields']['format'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a key exists in a dict, do
`if key in dict:
  ...`

So, in your case,
`if 'lignes' in i['fields']:
  ...`

Currently, you are checking whether the *value* of `i['fields']['lignes']` is a *key* of `data`, which doesn't make sense, and also might be throwing an exception before the whole line even finishes evaluating, i.e. it might error when it's evaluating `i['fields']['lignes']`, because you haven't yet checked whether `'lignes'` is a key of `i['fields']`.